# Adding runtime dependency jars with maven

Tags: maven

Is there a way to include runtime dependency jar to maven project. Basically I want to include project1 as dependency jar at runtime to project2.

Project1

```
src/main/java
com.test.example1
```

Project2

```
src/main/java
    com.test.example2
    lib
```

I received error - 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.test.example2.PublishItem:jar must be omitted. This field may only be specified for a dependency with system scope

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.example2</groupId>
        <artifactId>PublishItem</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/lib/</systemPath>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not just build one project and then use it in the other

Comment: You might want to read what [scope=runtime](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) means.

Comment: I want to know if there is any way to automatically include custom dependency jar at runtime using maven build.